# Maximum moduli of $f(z)= \cos3z$ and $g(z)= \frac{2z+1}{2z-1}$ on $\bar B(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> What are the maximum moduli of (a) $f(z) = \cos3z$ and (b) $g(z) = \frac{2z+1}{2z-1}$ on $\bar B(0,1)$?

Attempt:

Clearly we will want to use the maximum modulus principle for (a) and for (b) I am not sure at all, as $g$ has a simple pole at $z= \frac{1}{2}$, which is inside $\bar B(0,1)$.

If anyone could help me out here that would be great! Many thanks!

Comment: for $\cos(3z)$, use Cauchy's formula $\displaystyle \cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$, and write $z=x+iy$ with $x$, $y$ real.
For the other one, if you write $z=x+iy$ you can find and explicit rational expression for $|g(z)|^2=g(z)\overline{g(z)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed $g$ is not defined at $\frac 1 2$ so b) does not make  sense.

For a) write $z$ on the boundary as $e^{it}$ with $t$ real. You can see that $|cos 3z| \leq \sup_t \frac {e^{-3\sin t} +e^{3\sin t}} 2$. Now use the fact that $\frac {x+\frac  1 x} 2$ is increasing in $[-1,1]$ to see that the maximum is attained when $\sin t=1$. Hence $|\cos 3z| \leq \frac {e^{-3}+e^{3}} 2$ . This value is attained when $t=\frac {\pi} 2$ which means $z=i$. Hence the answer to a) is $\frac {{e^{-3}+e^{3}}} 2$ .

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Also is $\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{2}$ really increasing in $[−1,1]$... I think $\frac{e^x+e^{−x}}{2}$ is increasing however!? Could you explain?

Comment: @user736948 If $f(x)=\frac {x+\frac 1 x} 2$ and $g(x)=e^{x}$ then $\frac {e^{x}+e^{-x}} 2=f(g(x))$. Hence it is increasing.